# Storing a variable in one for loop to be used in next loop bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I want to write a script which will take the output of a job submission script as a variable to be used for the same next for loop. I have written it as follows

```
temp= (40 50)
for  i in "${!temp[@]}"; do
  cd ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns;
  ((counter++))
  var="ID$((counter-1))"
  var1=ID$counter
  if [[ "$i" -eq 0]]; then
    var1=$(qsub jobsubmission.sh);
  else
    var1=$(qsub -W depend=afterok:${var} jobsubmission.sh);
  fi
  cd ..;
done
```

The script goes into a directory, submits a job then goes into the next directory and submits a job based on dependancy of the job created in the first loop. The problem in this script is that the variable "var" is not taking the value of variable assigned in the before loop. Please suggest a way.

Comment: There are some syntax errors in there. Paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and make the suggested changes

Comment: After correcting for all the errors by pasting it in shellcheck.net, the problem is still not solved.

Comment: Spellcheck will never address functional logic issues.   Only syntax correctness.

Comment: An ideal Stack Overflow question has _only one_ technical problem, with everything unrelated to that problem removed. Code with other bugs (like `temp= (40 50)` instead of `temp=( 40 50 )` makes it hard to focus on the narrow, specific center of the question, as the code needs other fixes applied before one can even start to evaluate the question at the core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In trying to simplify your script for troubleshooting, I identified the two "**!**" are extraneous, preventing the array values from being derived.

Also, it is not advisable to reuse the same variable for looping in multiple loops within the same code.

Lastly, to pass position-dependant values to the second loop for, again, position-dependant usage, you need to assign those values to another array.

The distilled logic flow and diagnostic coding is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#lastVal=""
altVal=()
temp=( 50 60 )
action()
{
    #for  i in  "${!temp[@]}"
    for  i in  "${temp[@]}"
    do
        echo "i = ${i}"
        #lastVal="ABC_${i}"
        altVal[$i]="ABC_${i}"
        #mkdir ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns
        #cd ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns
        #lastVal=$(qsub jobsubmission.sh)
        #cd ..
    done
}

#action lastVal
action
echo ""

temp=( 60 70)
#for  j in  "${!temp[@]}" 
for  j in  "${temp[@]}" 
do
    echo "j = ${j}"
    previous=$( expr ${j} - 10 )
    echo "${altVal[ ${previous} ]}"
    echo ""
    #mkdir ${temp[j]}-$((temp[j]+10))ns
    #cd ${temp[j]}-$((temp[j]+10))ns
    #var1=$(qsub -W  depend=afterok:${lastVal} jobsubmission.sh)
    #cd ..
done
```

and the session log is this:

```
ericthered@OasisMega1:/WORKS$ ./test_41.sh
i = 50
i = 60

j = 60
ABC_50

j = 70
ABC_60

ericthered@OasisMega1:/WORKS$
```

Comment: If this addresses the intent of your very unclear question, please click on the grayed-out check-mark next to my answer.  I will then know to delete my other answer to avoid propagating confusion in the community.

Comment: Apologies for any miscommunication. But the trick worked for the script.

Answer (score 0):

The script is given below

```
#!/bin/sh
   action()
  {
 **temp=(50 )**
 for  i in  "${!temp[@]}"  ;
   do
   mkdir ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns
  cd ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns;
 lastVal=$(qsub jobsubmission.sh);
 cd ..;
 done
 }
action lastVal
  //temp=(60 )
 for  i in  "${!temp[@]}"  ;
 do
 mkdir ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns
 cd ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns;
 var1=$(qsub -W  depend=afterok:${lastVal} jobsubmission.sh);
 cd ..;
 done //
```

The problem is in the asterisk(***) part. The function outputs the **lastVal** to be used in the main loop. In the function action(), I cannot use two values for the loop as the output value of the function will be used for the next loop like I have done for
the part enclosed in // //. So, here, I have used the output of i loop for i+1 loop. Subsequently, I have to use the value of i+1 loop for i+2 loop and so on.

Comment: The two loops above are fully independent.  There is no dependency of the 2nd loop on the first loop (first loop is not called by second loop).  So ... what the exact problem encountered is not clear.  Maybe you could expand your explanation with a point-form step-by-step sequencing of events to clarify the inter-dependency between the two action functions and "what action/operation" should be nested within "what else".  My first interpretation was that the second loop, depending on the results of the first, required to contain the first.  But the above shows clearly that is not.  Confused.

Comment: Please look at the comment given below.

Answer (score 0):

```
action()
  {
 temp=(50 )
 for  i in  "${!temp[@]}"  ;
   do
   mkdir ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns
  cd ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns;
 lastVal=$(qsub jobsubmission.sh);
 cd ..;
 done
 }
```

This do loop is for making one directory (`mkdir ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns`), entering it (`cd ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns`) and submit one job, the output of which is lastVal `{lastVal=$(qsub jobsubmission.sh)}`.

```
action lastVal
```

This is for calling the script. The script is not incorporated in the second loop as otherwise the loop would be executed depending on the number of variables (temp).

```
temp=(60 )
 for  i in  "${!temp[@]}"  ;
 do
 mkdir ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns
 cd ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns;
 var1=$(qsub -W  depend=afterok:${lastVal} jobsubmission.sh);
 cd ..;
 done
```

This loop is for making another directory (`mkdir ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns`), entering it (`cd ${temp[i]}-$((temp[i]+10))ns`) and submit a job, depending on the output of the first loop which is lastVal. `{var1=$(qsub -W  depend=afterok:${**lastVal**} jobsubmission.sh);}`.

Here, the output of one loop is incorporated into another loop. But in this way, one could submit only two jobs. The best way would be to incorporate the result of `i` loop into `i+1` loop. And result of `i+1` loop into `i+2` loop. Please suggest.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given below based on answer by @Eric Marceau. A lot of thanks to @Eric Marceau. Apologies for miscommunication to the community.

```
#!/bin/bash
      tem=( 10 20 30 )
     for i in  "${!tem[@]}"  ;
     do
     mkdir ${tem[i]}-$((tem[i]+10))ns;
     cd ${tem[i]}-$((tem[i]+10))ns;
           previous=$( expr ${i} - 1 )
       if [[ "$i" -eq 0 ]]; then
           altVal[$i]=$(qsub jobsubmission.sh);
        else
           echo "${altVal[ ${previous} ]}"
        altVal[$i]=$(qsub -W  depend=afterok:${altVal[ ${previous}]} jobsubmission.sh);
        fi
          cd ..;
            done
```

The answer is broken into parts.

```
if [[ "$i" -eq 0 ]]; then
altVal[$i]=$(qsub jobsubmission.sh);
```

This line is for submitting the job for the very first loop. Based on this output, the next loop job will be submitted.

```
          else
           echo "${altVal[ ${previous} ]}"
        altVal[$i]=$(qsub -W  depend=afterok:${altVal[ ${previous}]} jobsubmission.sh);
        fi
```

This is the part for submitting the job in the next loop based on outcome of the previous loop which is given by ${altVal[ ${previous}]}. And previous is given by
previous=$( expr ${i} - 1 ). Like this, the job in the next loop will again be submitted based on outcome from the previous loop which is ${altVal[ ${previous}]}.
I hope I am able to address the query and this will be beneficial for the community.